# Adding colour bar to my figure in Gephi

Tags: colorbar, gephi

I have created a network in Gephi. There is a particular node attribute (float values) that I have added to the nodes of my network. The colour of each node corresponds to this particular quantity which I have added as a node attribute. Now, I want to add a colour bar (for this node attribute) beside the figure for my network. Is that possible and how can I do that?

Comment: It would be nice but you can't do it right away with Gephi

Comment: You could however save the graph as GraphML or GEXF and experiment a bit with `matplotlib` or R